# Challenging integral for Gaussian average

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is a tough integral that I'm not quite sure how to do. It's the Gaussian average:

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{1+a^2 \sinh^2(b x)}
$$

for $0 < a < 1$ and $b > 0$. Obviously the integral can be done for $a = 0$ (or $b=0$) and for $a=1$. But otherwise, I'm stomped? Expanding the root in powers of $a$, we can do all the integrals in the series and get a power series. But the sequences I get don't seem easy to work with.

I'm curious if there is an elegant way to do this? Is it even doable?

Ben

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for an analytical solution (if it exists).

Edit 2: I thought I was on MathematicS Stack Exchange, not MathematicA Stack Exchange. Ulrich's answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If a numerical solution is ok try

```
int[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi] Sqrt[1 + a^2 Sinh[b x]^2], {x, -Infinity,Infinity}]

Plot3D[int[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for an analytical solution. Numerically and in some important limits, I can do it fine. But I'm curious to know if it can be done analytically exactly.

Comment: I didn't mean to post on Mathematica StackExchange. My bad. I'm so sorry. Your answer is good in this context, accepted.